# HTML CSS DIV Layout with Top, Left, and Right DIVs fixed with a scrolling Center DIV

Tags: html, css, layout

Picture (no rep yet to post)
https://flic.kr/p/ppcZtV

Here is what I have so far, and I am not sure the jsFiddle represents it: http://jsfiddle.net/5jeymu5f/
(I commented out stuff from my site to make the example simpler)

What I am trying to do and see the attached picture, I want basically everything fixed as they are menus of sorts.  All content is entered in the purple 'content' section.  Some pages get to long and you have to scroll down which kills everything up top.  I have multiple 'to the top' links with an anchor, but I do not want to have to use those.  The picture is just illustration for position, not correct sizes.

Also, my right pane does not even show up in the code. I tried putting fixed all over the board and not sure where to go next.

How can I, keep top wrapper, left navigation, and right space fixed in the position where they are at and just have only my middle content section scroll?

```css
#container {
 width: 1440px;
 /* background-image: url(../graphics/wall.jpg); */
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: auto;
 position: fixed;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#top-wrapper {
 width: 1080px;
 float: left;
 /* margin: 10px; */
 /* background-image: url(../graphics/transparent.png); */
 margin-bottom: 13px;
 position: fixed;
    background-color: #DF0101;
}

#top {
 background-color: #FFEF0F;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

#pagetitle {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 background-color: #ffef0f;
 /* background-image: url(../graphics/caution_long.gif); 
 background-repeat: repeat;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 border-bottom-style: none;
 border-left-style: none;
 color: #F63;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 18px; */
 height: 24px;
 clear: both;
 
}

#content-wrapper {
 float: none;
 width:auto
 background-color: #0080FF;
 width: 1080px;
 /* background-image: url(../graphics/transparent.png); */
 margin-top: 200px;
 
}

#left {
 float: left;
 background-color: #8000FF;
 width: 17%;
 margin-right: 10px;
 /* position: fixed; */
}
#content {
 float: right;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #8000FF;
 overflow: scroll;
 height: 1080px;
}


#right {
 float: right;
 background-color: #01DF01;
 width: 20%;
 /* position: fixed; */
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id="top-wrapper">

        <div id="top">
            top banner
        </div>

        <div id="pagetitle">
            page title banner
        </div>
  
    </div>

    <div align="top" id="right" title="right pane">
        right pane
    </div>

    <div id="content-wrapper">

        <div id="left">
            navigation menu
        </div>
        
        <div id="content">
            main content
        </div>
  
    </div>

<div class="clear"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: hard code heights into it.  set container to x pixels, set internal elements to relative position and set their heights to their respective approximation using %. #content {height:33.3%;}

Comment: just as you have now, you're not seeing it because you have no content and you set a very long height for `#content`. Try adding content and reducing that height and you'll see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `position: fixed` from `#container`. Then don't use  `float: right` for fixed elements but `right: 0`, it will give you a more comprehensive view of what happen. Doing this (and removing the overflow property) I come to a pretty convincing result where you just have to play with the width and the position of the divs to make it looks good. : )

```
#container {
    width: 1440px;
    /* background-image: url(../graphics/wall.jpg); */
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#top-wrapper {
    width: 1080px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    /* margin: 10px; */
    /* background-image: url(../graphics/transparent.png); */
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #DF0101;
}

#top {
    background-color: #FFEF0F;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

#pagetitle {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffef0f;
    /* background-image: url(../graphics/caution_long.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    color: #F63;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 18px; */
    height: 24px;
    clear: both;

}

#content-wrapper {
    float: none;
    width:auto
    background-color: #0080FF;
    width: 1080px;
    /* background-image: url(../graphics/transparent.png); */
    margin-top: 200px;

}

#left {
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #8000FF;
    width: 17%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: fixed;
}
#content {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #8000FF;
    /*overflow: scroll;*/
    height: 1080px;
}


#right {
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #01DF01;
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    clear: both;
}
```

## Edit : Second Issue - width of content do not fit.

I've use some jQuery to solve this one, it may be possible in css but I'm more familiar with jQuery to be honest.

**First the css**

```
/* ***** Reset css ******** */
/* I've added this part since I noticed strange bwhite border due to
 * default css parameter of browser (I use Firefox) */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* ************************ */


#container {
    /* width: 1440px; * deleted */
    /* background-image: url(../graphics/wall.jpg); */
    /*margin-top: 0; * deleted */
    /*margin-right: auto; * deleted */
    margin: 0;
    /*margin-bottom: 0px; * deleted */
    /*margin-left: auto; * deleted */
    background-color: #000000;
}

#top-wrapper {
    width: 1080px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    /* margin: 10px; */
    /* background-image: url(../graphics/transparent.png); */
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #DF0101;
}

#top {
    background-color: #FFEF0F;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

#pagetitle {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffef0f;
    /* background-image: url(../graphics/caution_long.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    color: #F63;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 18px; */
    height: 24px;
    clear: both;

}

#content-wrapper {
    float: none;
    width:auto
    background-color: #0080FF;
    width: 1080px;
    /* background-image: url(../graphics/transparent.png); */
    margin-top: 200px;

}

#left {
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #8000FF;
    width: 200px; /* changed to pixel size */
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: fixed;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    left: 200px; /* changed to pixel size (this should be equal #left.width !) */
    background-color: #8000FF;
    height: 1080px;
}


#right {
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #01DF01;
    width: 200px; /* changed to pixel size */
    position: fixed;
    clear: both;
}
```

Not much has been changed, only removing width from `#content` and changing width to pixel in `#left` and `#right`. Plz also note that you need to change the left parameter of `#content` to the width of right.

**The jQuery in the HTML**

I've added this part in the `<head>` of the html. I tried to explain it but if you have any question please ask.

```
<!-- Import of the JQuery library on the jQuery website (you can upload it and use it localy) -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get the width of the #left and #right divs
  var leftWidth = $('#left').width();
  var rightWidth = $('#right').width();

  function setWidth() {
    // get the width that content should have basically here :
    // width of the window - width of left - width of right
    var widthContent = $(window).width() - leftWidth - rightWidth;

    // Choose here the minimal width of content
    var minContentWidth = 300;

    // set the width of content to min width if necessary
    if (widthContent < minContentWidth) {
        widthContent = minContentWidth;
    }

    // get the content div and set its width
    $('#content').css({
      'width': widthContent + 'px'
    });
  }

  // when the windows is rezised call the function resize
  $(window).on('resize', function() { setWidth(); });
  setHeight();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I had added as suggest and was just what i was looking for.  I did have to mess with the positioning.  I have it almost all set.  My only problem is the right div - now when the browser is reduced in size stays where it is at and covers everything as the window gets smaller.  Everything else is 'fixed position' and when i scroll the content moves so TY for that =F  Any suggestions on keeping the right pane from covering everything upon decreased window size? (dont have enough rep to vote up yet)

Comment: I've modify my answer to solve your issue hope this help. There might be a way to do is just in css but it was esier for me to use jQuery. I've try to explain it if since you may be not familiar with jQuery. If you have any question I'll be happy to answer.
ps: You can't upvote but you can accept the answer if it solved your problem : )

Comment: I have not used jquery before and do not really understand it, if you can briefly explain it but when I edited it in jsfiddle it shrinks the content window when reducing the window size.  Both the left, right, and top panes stay frozen- just the content now shrinks as the right pane closes into the left.

Comment: Have you edit both css and HTML ? I have tried to comment the JS to explain each line what dont you understand ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, it looks like you are trying to do the same thing. [Scrolling only content div, others should be fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954181/scrolling-only-content-div-others-should-be-fixed).

Adding "overflow: auto;" to your content-wrapper would do the trick. You will also need a fixed height.

Comment: similarly, ty for suggestion - I attempted changes but still was not doing what was intended.