# Scrolling only side menu div and others should be fixed when menu is open

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, overflow, css-position

I have a side menu and when it's open, the body can be partially seen. My side menu might be long so you could scroll on it. But when the menu is at the bottom you then scroll on the body, and I don't want this behaviour.

Similar to [Scrolling only content div, others should be fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954181/scrolling-only-content-div-others-should-be-fixed) but I'm using React. Other content should be scrollable when my side menu is closed. Think of the content as side menu in the example in the link. So far I'm using the same technique provided by that answer but it's ugly (kinda jQuery):

```
preventOverflow = (menuOpen) => { // this is called when side menu is toggled
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; // this should be fixed when side menu is open

    if (menuOpen) {
        body.className += ' overflow-hidden';
    } else {
        body.className = body.className.replace(' overflow-hidden', '');
    }
}

// css
.overflow-hidden {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

What should I do with Reactjs?

Comment: Looks like react-modal is doing the same thing: https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/blob/master/lib/components/Modal.js#L133-L137

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS doesn't have direct access to the `<body>` element, and that's the element that needs to have its `overflow-y` style changed.  So while what you're doing isn't perhaps the prettiest code, it's not entirely wrong either.

The only real suggestion I'd give is (**shudder**) using inline styles on the body instead of a classname so as to avoid having to introduce the CSS declaration.  As long as your menu is the only thing responsible for updating the `overflow-y` attribute, there's no reason you can't use an inline style on it.  Mashing that down with the `?:` operator results in fairly simple code:

```
body.style.overflowY = menuOpen ? "hidden" : "";
```

And then you can just delete the `.overflow-hidden` class in its entirety.

If for some reason multiple things are managing the overflow state of the body, you might want to stick with classnames and assign a unique one for each thing managing it, something like this:

```
if (menuOpen) {
    body.className += ' menu-open';
}
else {
    // Use some tricks from jQuery to remove the "menu-open" class more elegantly.
    var className = " " + body.className + " ";
    className = className.replace(" overflow-hidden ", " ").replace(/\s+/, " ");
    className = className.substr(1, className.length - 2);     
}
```

CSS:

```
body.menu-open {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using inline style or class or better way to handle class isn't the point of this question. But Sadly there's no better way :( Also I'd like to hear from whoever down voted this answer. Cheer :)

Comment: React is just javascript to say this can't be done in react makes no sense. You can create a component that will change document meta tags, title, link.. etc as well as body classes and id.

Comment: React has a very specific view of the universe that doesn't include reaching out to the DOM outside its root.  Without the hackery of `react-side-effect` and friends, and effectively having a separate set of components for managing just the head and body (and none of their children), you really can't do what he's asking for using _just_ ReactJS itself.  Your example code reaches outside the React ecosystem to accomplish its task too.

Comment: react-side-effect has nothing to do with rackery or reaching out of the root. Yes you need to use javascript to effect the dom but theres nothing wrong with that. it doesn't mess with React and how react works... React is just javascript, at some level or another everything is a DOM operation.

Comment: I'll rescind my downvote, but I still think your answer doesn't really provide much help. Recommending inline styles instead of a class isn't much of an improvement (if at all)

Comment: It's slightly simpler code, at least in his case. But I don't think it's wrong to claim that ReactJS (by itself) doesn't have direct access to the `<body>` element. Yes, it's just JS, and JS can technically interact with any part of the DOM directly (and even that's assuming that, say, you're not running under a server-side fake DOM for unit-testing).  But if you're trying to do things "the React way," there's no way to touch the `<body>` (unless your initial render target was the `<body>` itself, and I'm not sure that would actually work; I probably ought to try that sometime).

Answer (score 0):

You should make a meta component in react to change things on the body as well as changing things like document title and things like that. I made one a while ago to do that for me. I'll add it here.

#### Usage

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
             <DocumentMeta bodyClasses={[isMenuOpen ? 'no-scroll' : '']} />
            ... rest of your normal code
        </div>
    )
}
```

#### DocumentMeta.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import withSideEffect from 'react-side-effect';

var HEADER_ATTRIBUTE = "data-react-header";
var TAG_NAMES = {
  META: "meta",
  LINK: "link",
};
var TAG_PROPERTIES = {
  NAME: "name",
  CHARSET: "charset",
  HTTPEQUIV: "http-equiv",
  REL: "rel",
  HREF: "href",
  PROPERTY: "property",
  CONTENT: "content"
};
var getInnermostProperty = (propsList, property) => {
  return _.result(_.find(propsList.reverse(), property), property);
};

var getTitleFromPropsList = (propsList) => {
  var innermostTitle = getInnermostProperty(propsList, "title");
  var innermostTemplate = getInnermostProperty(propsList, "titleTemplate");
  if (innermostTemplate && innermostTitle) {
      return innermostTemplate.replace(/\%s/g, innermostTitle);
  }
  return innermostTitle || "";
};
var getBodyIdFromPropsList = (propsList) => {
  var bodyId = getInnermostProperty(propsList, "bodyId");
  return bodyId;
};
var getBodyClassesFromPropsList = (propsList) => {
  return propsList
    .filter(props => props.bodyClasses && Array.isArray(props.bodyClasses))
    .map(props => props.bodyClasses)
    .reduce((classes, list) => classes.concat(list), []);
};
var getTagsFromPropsList = (tagName, uniqueTagIds, propsList) => {
  // Calculate list of tags, giving priority innermost component (end of the propslist)
  var approvedSeenTags = {};
  var validTags = _.keys(TAG_PROPERTIES).map(key => TAG_PROPERTIES[key]);

  var tagList = propsList
    .filter(props => props[tagName] !== undefined)
    .map(props => props[tagName])
    .reverse()
    .reduce((approvedTags, instanceTags) => {
      var instanceSeenTags = {};

      instanceTags.filter(tag => {
        for(var attributeKey in tag) {
          var value = tag[attributeKey].toLowerCase();
          var attributeKey = attributeKey.toLowerCase();

          if (validTags.indexOf(attributeKey) == -1) {
              return false;
          }
          if (!approvedSeenTags[attributeKey]) {
              approvedSeenTags[attributeKey] = [];
          }
          if (!instanceSeenTags[attributeKey]) {
              instanceSeenTags[attributeKey] = [];
          }

          if (!_.has(approvedSeenTags[attributeKey], value)) {
              instanceSeenTags[attributeKey].push(value);
              return true;
          }
          return false;
        }
      })
      .reverse()
      .forEach(tag => approvedTags.push(tag));

      // Update seen tags with tags from this instance
      _.keys(instanceSeenTags).forEach((attr) => {
        approvedSeenTags[attr] = _.union(approvedSeenTags[attr], instanceSeenTags[attr])
      });
      instanceSeenTags = {};
      return approvedTags;
    }, []);
  return tagList;
};
var updateTitle = title => {
  document.title = title || document.title;
};
var updateBodyId = (id) => {
  document.body.setAttribute("id", id);
};
var updateBodyClasses = classes => {
  document.body.className = "";
  classes.forEach(cl => {
    if(!cl || cl == "") return;
    document.body.classList.add(cl);
  });
};
var updateTags = (type, tags) => {
  var headElement = document.head || document.querySelector("head");
  var existingTags = headElement.querySelectorAll(`${type}[${HEADER_ATTRIBUTE}]`);
  existingTags = Array.prototype.slice.call(existingTags);
  // Remove any duplicate tags
  existingTags.forEach(tag => tag.parentNode.removeChild(tag));

  if (tags && tags.length) {
    tags.forEach(tag => {
      var newElement = document.createElement(type);
      for (var attribute in tag) {
        if (tag.hasOwnProperty(attribute)) {
            newElement.setAttribute(attribute, tag[attribute]);
        }
      }
      newElement.setAttribute(HEADER_ATTRIBUTE, "true");
      headElement.insertBefore(newElement, headElement.firstChild);
    });
  }
};
var generateTagsAsString = (type, tags) => {
  var html = tags.map(tag => {
  var attributeHtml = Object.keys(tag)
    .map((attribute) => {
        const encodedValue = HTMLEntities.encode(tag[attribute], {
            useNamedReferences: true
        });
        return `${attribute}="${encodedValue}"`;
    })
    .join(" ");
    return `<${type} ${attributeHtml} ${HEADER_ATTRIBUTE}="true" />`;
  });
  return html.join("\n");
};

var reducePropsToState = (propsList) => ({
  title: getTitleFromPropsList(propsList),
  metaTags: getTagsFromPropsList(TAG_NAMES.META, [TAG_PROPERTIES.NAME, TAG_PROPERTIES.CHARSET, TAG_PROPERTIES.HTTPEQUIV, TAG_PROPERTIES.CONTENT], propsList),
  linkTags: getTagsFromPropsList(TAG_NAMES.LINK, [TAG_PROPERTIES.REL, TAG_PROPERTIES.HREF], propsList),
  bodyId: getBodyIdFromPropsList(propsList),
  bodyClasses: getBodyClassesFromPropsList(propsList),
});
var handleClientStateChange = ({title, metaTags, linkTags, bodyId, bodyClasses}) => {
  updateTitle(title);
  updateTags(TAG_NAMES.LINK, linkTags);
  updateTags(TAG_NAMES.META, metaTags);
  updateBodyId(bodyId);
  updateBodyClasses(bodyClasses)
};
var mapStateOnServer = ({title, metaTags, linkTags}) => ({
  title: HTMLEntities.encode(title),
  meta: generateTagsAsString(TAG_NAMES.META, metaTags),
  link: generateTagsAsString(TAG_NAMES.LINK, linkTags)
});

var DocumentMeta = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    title: React.PropTypes.string,
    titleTemplate: React.PropTypes.string,
    meta: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object),
    link: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object),
    children: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
        React.PropTypes.object,
        React.PropTypes.array
    ]),
    bodyClasses: React.PropTypes.array,
  },
  render() {
    if (Object.is(React.Children.count(this.props.children), 1)) {
        return React.Children.only(this.props.children);
    } else if (React.Children.count(this.props.children) > 1) {
        return (
            <span>
                {this.props.children}
            </span>
        );
    }
    return null;
  },
});
DocumentMeta = withSideEffect(reducePropsToState, handleClientStateChange, mapStateOnServer)(DocumentMeta);
module.exports = DocumentMeta;
```

This component could probably be changed a little for your case (withSideEffect is used for both client and server side rendering... if you arent using server side rendering then its probably not completely necessary) but the component will work on client side rendering if you would like to use it there as well.