# HTML/CSS Div scrolling into element above

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have 2 div elements on a HTML page. The first div is supposed to be the top header section (fixed), with the one below it a scrollable content div.

The header section is using position fixed and does not scroll. However, when I scroll the second div, it ends up moving up behind the div above it.

Is there a way to prevent this so that the second div does not scroll up above its initial top location?

Also, the scrollbar itself has the height of the entire page (including the top section). Is there a way to limit the scroll bar to just the second div element.

I have tried several permutations, including answers referenced on this  page: [Scrolling only content div, others should be fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954181/scrolling-only-content-div-others-should-be-fixed)

HTML Code (Snippet):

```css
.Toolbar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #40A4C8;
    padding: 0 20px;
    z-index: 90;
}

.Layout {
    top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: orange;
}

.Items {
}

.Items li {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div>
    <header class="Toolbar">
    </header>
    <main class="Layout">
        <div class="Items">
            <ul>
                <li><p>Item A</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
                <li><p>Item B</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than fixing your header, why not just add scroll to your body - below I have made it so that the page is always the size of the viewport and then the body overflows

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Toolbar {
  min-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #40A4C8;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.Layout {
  top: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.Items {}

.Items li {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="Toolbar">
  </header>
  <main class="Layout">
    <div class="Items">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>Item A</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Item B</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `position` css property is working the way it should by fixing the position of the first div element. Even if you prevent the second div element from going behind the first div element with some workaround, it'd still look kind of very similar effect. At least you can add `height` css property to the `Items` class to limit the size of second div element.